# Rails: rake db:test:prepare Vs rake test:prepare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

AS the guides, the command used to prepare test database is

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

However, I have found that following command also works & created the test db for me.

```
bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

Wanted to know if this is a valid command, if yes. Where can I find the documentation.

tested on `rails 3.2.8`

Comment: so did you ever found out if both are the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [github and the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake) `task 'test:prepare' => 'db:test:prepare'` is mentioned at the bottom.

Hence it's a shortcut, wrapper, whatever you want to call it.  Another question would be why this doesn't up when you do `bundle exec rake -T` but hey.

Comment: So, I found a easter egg in rails :)

Comment: Only rake tasks with a `desc "some description"` before the task definition will show up with `rake -T`.  I'm guessing that the `test:prepare` task is missing this.

Comment: These don't actually appear to be aliases for one another, if you look at the source. test:prepare has more prerequisites than db:test:prepare.